# background-size: cover not responsive

Tags: css, mobile, background, responsive-design

So I have a full screen background set up like so:

```
#div {
    background-image: url("images/slide1.jpg");
    background-position: center 20%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The background image resizes according to all view ports sizes, but when I view the site from my mobile, it seems to be displaying a very small section of the whole image - basically the `background-size: cover;` rule doesn't seem to working. It should also be noted that if I make the window on my computer phone size, the background resizes properly. It also resizes properly when I view it using the responsive display tool 'responsivetest.net'. Just not when I actually open it on a phone.

Any suggestions are, as always, much appreciated.

Comment: What phone, mainly the OS and version? Then use http://caniuse.com to make sure that the OS/version actually supports `background-size : cover`.

Comment: thanks @Jasper that's a nice resource to have. Still according to that list, it is supported.

Comment: @Jasper All background-options

Comment: I'm asking what OS/version of a mobile device you are testing on. Also posting what desktop browsers your testing on as well. This is key information for getting help.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am using version 7.0.2 on my iphone and have tested the site on firefox, safari, chrome and ie.

Comment: Try removing the `background-attachment : fixed` portion of your CSS. Or changing the value to `scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar for a portfolio site that's in development and it works fine on mobile. Here's my working code for CSS:

```
    display: table;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 100px 0;
background: url(../img/bbg1.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

So you can see some things you can try changing, such as the display height.

Test this site on your [mobile device](http://triplewww.com/startbs/)

Comment: Thanks @user3362232 when I change the height to auto, the background image only covers as much as the padding around the content allows - not full screen. I guess I can nest it all in a div set to `height: 100%;` ?